# Inline Entity Form Order by field value

Tags: forms, entities

I'm attempting to sort the form table generated by IEF by the value of a specific field - but running into a stumbling block (in other words - it's not working). Has anyone else used the hook_inline_entity_form_table_alter and sorted by a field value successfully?

Comment: Did you get it working? If so please share :)

Answer (score 0):

I did it using hook_form_alter().

If you have a field with an inline entity form:

```
$form['field_newsletter_content'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['entities'];
```

Then you can change the '#weight' property on the individual entities.

So, to change the weight of element 0 to 1, do this.

```
$form['field_newsletter_content'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['entities'][0]['#weight'] = 1;
```

And if you change the weight of element 1 to 0, then they will have traded places in the inline entity form.